# How to get MAC address of Android hotspot client that fails to obtain IP address?

Tags: android, macos, wifi

I have seen solutions for getting the MAC address of a successfully connected hotspot client, from an app running on an Android device with hotspot turned on.  However, I have not seen one that gives the MAC address of a hotspot client that fails to connect (that is, attempts to connect to the hotspot, but fails to obtain an IP address because of authentication failure).

The reason I am looking for the MAC address of such a failed hotspot client is because I would like to take note of the Wifi devices nearby.  Then I can sort of identify people nearby, similar to advertising systems.  Just that I do it with a normal Android phone, while they rely on specialized hardware.

I cannot expect a successful hotspot connection, because the Android hotspot device crashes and reboots if I attempt to turn hotspot on with an authentication configuration that is different from what the user has already set.  Android detects it as some system violation and reboots.  Neither is this a desired approach, because I would prefer to leave the hotspot configuration untouched.  This is another reason I would like to get failed clients.

Has anyone got an idea how this can be done?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please look this

```
 public static String getMACAddress(String interfaceName) {
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface
                .getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
            if (interfaceName != null) {
                if (!intf.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(interfaceName))
                    continue;
            }
            byte[] mac = intf.getHardwareAddress();
            if (mac == null)
                return "";
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            for (int idx = 0; idx < mac.length; idx++)
                buf.append(String.format("%02X:", mac[idx]));
            if (buf.length() > 0)
                buf.deleteCharAt(buf.length() - 1);
            return buf.toString();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } // for now eat exceptions
    return "";

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I am looking for a way to get the MAC address of a client device.  Specifically, the MAC address of a client device that could not get an IP address from me (assuming I am a phone with wifi hotspot turned on).  I am not trying to get my own MAC address.